# How to configure a router with eigrp and is-is in its interface (the code)

Tags: networking

I want to configure a router in order to have communication with two different network, but one use eigrp, and the other use is-is.

Answer (score 0):

are you able to provide the attempts you have made so far so that we can assist?

Taking a look online (my cisco gear is at home and I'm not!) - something like this would seem to work:

Router #1

=======

router eigrp 4321

network 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255

redistribute static

redistribute connected

!

Router #2

=======

router eigrp 4321

network 192.168.1.1 0.0.0.255

redistribute isis level-1 metric 102400 1000 255 255 1500

redistribute static

distance eigrp 110 110

!

router isis

net 47.0192.0168.0001.0002.00

redistribute static ip level-1-2

redistribute eigrp 4321 level-1-2

!

Router #3

=======

router isis

net 49.0192.00168.0001.0027.00

redistribute static ip level-1-2

!